# Nginx - How do I handle a SPA like react across a proxy?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, single-page-application

I have an app at `/myapp/` and then I need all sub paths to point back to `/myapp/index.html` and allow the internal routing to work

I also am hosting this on S3 based on environment, so

`..s3url.amazonaws.com/dev/myapp/`

`..s3url.amazonaws.com/prod/myapp/`

and would need a proxy_pass to serve the correct file.

Here is something I've tried recently, among hundreds of other iterations

```
location ~ $/myapp/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/myapp/index.html @proxy;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 = /dev/myapp/index.html;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass <s3-bucket>.amazonaws.com;
}
```